# Most efficent Way to get lowest 10 bits of a hash as an int in Python

Tags: python, binary, bit-manipulation

I am trying to get the first 10bits of sha256 hash as an integer, at the moment, I convert to a string and then trim that to 10 bits and convert back to an int.

This seems quite convoluted, is there a better way?

Code I borrowed from another post on here

```
def inttobin(i):
if i == 0:
    return "0"
s = ''
while i:
    if i & 1 == 1:
        s = "1" + s
    else:
        s = "0" + s
    i >>= 1
return s
```

Then Code I am using to convert to int is:

```
bin = inttobin(struct.unpack('H', hash[:2])[0]) 
idx = int(bin[-10:], 2)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that there is a `bin` built-in function that converts an integer to a string: i.e. `bin(3) -> "0b11"`. the `0b` is a prefix that is always present so you should do `bin(x)[2:]` to obtain the same result as your `inttobin`. The expression then reduces to `int(bin(struct.unpack('H', hash[:2])[0])[-10:], 2)`.

Comment: Presumably you are talking about the *hex digest* of the hash here?

Comment: Also: when computing the `sha256` you can compute the `digest()`, which return bytes. In python3 you could then do `(digest[-2] << 8 + digest[-1]) & 1023`. In python2 you have to add calls to `ord`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract certain bits as an integer, you can use Python's ["bitwise and", `&`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types).

For integer `i`, the first ten bits are `i & 1023` (`1023 == (2**10) - 1`). All bits higher than the tenth aren't in 1023, so will be zero.

A simple 4-bit example (`(2**4) - 1 == 15`):

```
a = 22 #     10110
b = 15 #      1111
a & b == 6 #  0110
```

Comment: Genius, I never thought of that. Works like a charm and is about twice as fast as the way I originally did it. so I now have `idx = struct.unpack('H', hash[:2])[0] & 1023` Thank you very much.